# How can I debug my emulated programs with GDB?

Tags: debugging, gdb, emulation

I wrote a simple fake processor emulator (dcpu-16). I would like to know if it's possible (and how) to integrate my target into gdb such that I could debug the programs compiled and executed in that emulator.

It seems like it would be related to the gdb "target" or maybe "target exec" commands although I didn't manage to understand how to make it work.

Any help would be appreciated :) Thanks!

Comment: You say "fake processor", does this mean that you are porting to a brand new architecture?  If this is the case you'll need to do far more than just wire in the simulator.

Comment: I mean that it's a virtual processor intended to be emulated in a game that will never sight the daylight (0x10c). Is it a brand new architecture? You tell me; p The specification is pretty simple. I was hoping there would be a way to wire it to gdb, but if not, so be it ...

Comment: dcpu-16 spec: https://gist.github.com/metaphox/3888117

Comment: Sure you can teach GDB to debug the architecture.  You'd first need to define the new architecture within the BFD library, then you can teach GDB to build for that architecture.  Next you'd want to add basic architecture support, this would take the form of a gdb/dcpu16-tdep.c file.  You likely don't need OS support, which helps.  In parallel you could add support for your architecture to the sim/ directory, this would result in a stand alone simulator, and a sim library than can be linked into GDB.  You could then use `target sim` to emulate your architecture.

Comment: If you already have a working simulator, then an alternative approach would be to add gdbserver support to the existing simulator.  You would still need to teach BFD/GDB about your architecture, but instead of adding code to sim/ directory, you teach your existing simulator how to talk to `target remote`.  Adding a new architecture to GDB is not massively hard, but it's not a trivial task either.  I'm not aware of any up to date guides for the task, your best bet is to look at GDB's git history, and look for new architectures being added.

Comment: ok thanks @andrew! I'll look into the gdbserver support. If you have any good links, please feel free to add them here :)